# wildcard or "in list" when querying in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, wildcard

I have a few tables where I need to get the data related to foo. The size of the tables are about 10^8 rows.

So I need to get all rows where the column include substring 'foo' from these tables.

```
select * from bar where my_col like '%foo%';
```

I know this is slow so I check the possible values:

```
select distinct my_col from bar where my_col like '%foo%';
-- => ('xx_foo', 'yy_foo', 'xx_foo_xx', 'foo' ... 'xx_foo_yy')
```

The number of possible values varies between 3 and 20.

Now how slow is '%foo%' really?

```
select * from bar where my_col like '%foo%';
-- or
select * from bar where my_col in('foo', 'xx_foo' ... 'foo_yy'); -- list_size = 20
```

Any general rule on when to use what, or is testing the speed for different cases the only way to go?

Edit: I do not own the table and no index exists on the column foo. So it needs to do a full table scan no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%foo%`, you will get a full-table scan, which is slow.

If you use `IN` with a list of values, than an index can be used if it exists on the column on which you have the condition.

So, if you are able, you should avoid using `%foo%`. Depending on how often new values may appear in the table, you might consider using an extra table holding the distinct values and use it when querying your main table, and update that extra table whenever new distinct value comes to play (if it is possible in your design).

Answer (score 1):

A search using the `like` operator will sure lead to a table scan when the pattern starts with a `%`. When using the `in` operator and the values are not more than a few percent of the values in the table an index can be used, if it exists. Check the cardinality concept:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29

The DBMS knows about the cardinalities keeping statistics about the tables. If your column has high cardinality and an index on it then an index scan is likely when using the `in` operator. To update the statistics issue an `analyze` command.

Comment: Ohh, forgot to mention that I do now own the table and it is very unlikely that I can influence any index creation on the column.